# Gradient a Parallelogram

Tags: javascript, gradient, shapes

I'm working in JavaScript drawing on a canvas, and have four coordinates to draw a parallelogram, called A, B, C, and D starting from the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom right, respectively.

An example of some coordinates might be:

A: (3, 3)

B: (4, 3)

C: (1, 0)

D: (2, 0)

I can draw the parallelogram just fine, but I would like to fill it in with a gradient.  I want the gradient to fill in from left to right, but matching the angle of the shape.  The library I use (CAKE) requires a start and stop coordinate for the gradient.  My stop and start would be somewhere half way between A and C, and end somewhere half way between B and D.  Of course, it is not simply EXACTLY half way because the angles at A, B, C, and D are not right angles.  So given this information (the coordinates), how to I find the point on the line A -> C to start, and the point on the line B -> D to stop?

Remember, I'm doing this in JavaScript, so I have some good Math tools at my disposal for calculation.

Comment: What does "the angle of the shape" mean?  The angle of the bottom line?  Top line?  Somewhere in between?

Comment: I suppose you could think of it as needing a line perpendicular to the line A -> C, and I need the points in which it would intersect A -> C (which would be the start), and where it would intersect the line B -> D (which would be the stop).

Answer (score 0):

What you specified in your comment is doable with more information (e.g. you need to specify where the perpendicular line starts as that will affect your gradient a lot), but I don't think it will get you what you want.

Instead, take the following for example, which I think is closer to what you are striving for:

[image]

As you can see, to make the gradient for the above parallelogram we ignore the **AC** and **BD** sides and make the gradient relative to **AB** and **CD**.  You can decide which pair of sides to use, but I would probably go by length so that the display is consistent across all your parallelograms (either you want the gradient relative to the pair of longer sides or the shorter ones, your choice, but personally I'd go with the longer sides).

Let's say you pick **AB**.  The slope of the line perpendicular to **AB** is the inverse reciprocal of the slope of **AB**, which is `(ax-bx)/(by-ay)` (careful about the dividing by zero case here!).

Next, you have to find 2 gradient points, which will be two appropriate points on any line with that slope.  One option is to pick the line going through **A**, use **A** as the starting point, and use the point where it intersects with **CD** as the ending point (you can use [this page](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html) as a guide for figuring out the intersection point).  Otherwise, keep the slope but tweak the points to your liking to get the gradient you want.

Once you have your points for your gradient, plug them in and it's a piece of CAKE!